# Different margin of div's are not working

Tags: css, margins

I want to make circles using divisions and each circle has different margin. The problem is that the `div` with small `margin-top` affects with the largest `margin top` for another `div`.

here's the HTML:

```
<div class="circle size2 marginTop2"></div>
<div class="circle size1 marginTop1" ></div>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
div.circle{

display: inline-block;
-moz-border-radius: 100px;
-webkit-border-radius: 100px;
-o-border-radius: 100px;
-ms-border-radius: 100px;
border-radius: 100px;
background: pink;
opacity: 0.3;
margin-top: 0px;
```

}

```
div.size1{
   width:120px;
   height:120px;
}

div.size2{
   width:130px;
   height:130px;
}

div.marginTop1{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right:-10px;
}
div.marginTop2{
 margin-top: 140px
 }
```

Here's the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/L6gPd/

The `div` with small `margin-top` affects with large margin top.

Any explanation please?

Comment: If you want to place them side by side then add `float:left;` to `div.circle`. If you inspect the element using Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools, you will see that the 2nd circle is have margin-top of just 20px but it is relative to the position of the 1st circle and not from the top of the page.

Comment: @Virendra, can you put it in the answers section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to place them side by side then add `float:left;` to `div.circle`.

If you inspect the element using Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools, you will see that the 2nd circle is having `margin-top` of just `20px` but it is relative to the position of the 1st circle and not from the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from your question, but are you trying to get them to be different heights vertically?  If so, would try adding

`vertical-align:top;` to the marginTop1 and marginTop2 classes so the margin-top values will take visible effect.

Comment: The problem was the second div is relative position for the first div not to the container div or the top of the page, it was solved using float:left, that make the divs relative to the top of the page.